# php array numbers comparison

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

Let's say I have

```
$input = ['1, 2, 3, 4, 5'];
```

and I need to get every number in the array that are stored as a string. Is there any possible way to use `foreach()` or anything else for every number in that string? In other words to retrieve numbers from string.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: loop and run is_string() on the values ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()` to split the string into numbers.

```
foreach ($input as $numberstring) {
    $numbers = explode(', ', $numberstring);
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the input array, because quotes dont make sense in terns of the question, let me know if this is wrong.

```
$input = [1, 2, 3, '4', 5];


foreach($input as $i){

    if(is_string($i)){//test if its a string
        $strings[]=$i; //put stings in array (you could do what you like here
    }

}
print_r($strings);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

your input is a single array element with one string of comma separated numbers

```
$input = ['1, 2, 3, 4, 5'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you could loop the array and check if the item from the array is a string using [is_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php). In your example the numbers are separated by a comma so you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and use a comma as the separator.

Then you could use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check the values from explode.

```
$input = ['1, 2, 3, 4, 5', 'test', 3, '100, a, test'];
foreach ($input as $item) {
    if (is_string($item)) {
        foreach (explode(',', $item) as $i) {
            if (is_numeric($i)) {
                echo trim($i) . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NgsiB)

That would result in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
100
```